# get max and min value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
Illinois: ['13', '12', '18', '23', '26', '25', '24', '19', '13', '10', '15', '14', '14', '4', '3']
Indiana: ['7', '6', '7', '8', '11', '11', '13', '12', '7', '7', '7', '7', '9', '2', '2']
```

Those are in my dictionary as d.
How would I get the largest and smallest value in each key in the dictionary and get the index where's the value is.

For example:
In Illinois, 26 is the largest value which is index 5 and 3 is the smallest value which is index 15.
in Indiana: 13 is largest value which is index 7 and 2 is the smallest value which is index 14

The output:

```
Illinois: 26 in index 5 and 3 in index 15
Indiana: 13 in index 7 and 2 in index 14
```

How would I do this?

```
d = {}
for row in csv_f:
    d[row[0]]=row[1:]
```

Comment: Can you show your own code attempt for this please? Explain what difficulties you are currently having. Ultimately, please show a [mcve]

Comment: @idjaw added, no idea how I would code this.........

Comment: literally this `max(list)` for max in list and `list.index(max[list])` for index position.

Comment: @Adib: `list.index(max(list))` will not find all occurrences.  It will find only the first.

Comment: @zondo shouldn't that be sufficient since you just want the max (and return only one index)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the max and mins printed out as your string is like this:

(assuming you only want the first occurrence)

```
 MY_D = {'Illinois': ['13', '12', '18', '23', '26', '25', '24', '19', '13', '10', '15', '14', '14', '4', '3'],
'Indiana': ['7', '6', '7', '8', '11', '11', '13', '12', '7', '7', '7', '7', '9', '2', '2']}

for k,v in MY_D.items():
     #This assumes that everything in v is an int, or rather can be converted to one.
     my_l = [int(n) for n in v]
     #if not
     #my_l = [int(n) for n in v if n.isdigit()]
     _max, _min = max(my_l), min(my_l)
     print("%s: Min - %d in index %d, Max - %d in index %d" % (k, _min,  my_l.index(_min), _max, my_l.index(_max)))
```

Comment: I have a question, let's say I replaced the first index in Illinois to empty string '', how would I get around that?

Comment: You'd write a case to handle that exception. `[int(n) for n in v if n]` or even better `[int(n) for n in v if n.isdigit()]`

Comment: Thank you! It's very helpful!

Comment: minor note - you don't need to cast to list when iterating over `items`.

Answer (score 0):

Bit thrown together, but seems to do the job.

```
d = {"Illinois": ['13', '12', '18', '23', '26', '25', '24', '19', '13', '10', '15', '14', '14', '4', '3'],
"Indiana": ['7', '6', '7', '8', '11', '11', '13', '12', '7', '7', '7', '7', '9', '2', '2']}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print d

    for state in d:
        # returns the numbers with their index (#, index)
        pairs = [(int(d[state][x]), x) for x in xrange(len(d[state]))]
        minpair = min(pairs)
        maxpair = max(pairs)
        print "%s: %d in index %d and %d in index %d"%(state,maxpair[0],maxpair[1],
        minpair[0],minpair[1])
```

Output:

```
{'Indiana': ['7', '6', '7', '8', '11', '11', '13', '12', '7', '7', '7', '7', '9', '2', '2'], 'Illinois': ['13', '12', '18', '23', '26', '25', '24', '19', '13', '10', '15', '14', '14', '4', '3']}
Indiana: 13 in index 6 and 2 in index 13
Illinois: 26 in index 4 and 3 in index 14
```

to get around the blank string, you could break up the list comprehension into

```
    pairs = []
    for x in xrange(len(d[state])):
        try:
            pairs.append( (int(d[state][x]), x) )
        except ValueError:
            pass # not a valid number
```

Comment: I have a question, let's say I replaced the first index in Illinois to empty string '', how would I get around that?

Comment: Fixed the main answer to answer the comment, as it wasn't formatting down here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution returning a dict `{country: (maxval, index), (minval, index))}`:

```
d = {
    'Illinois': ['13', '12', '18', '23', '26', '25', '24', '19', '13', '10', '15', '14', '14', '4', '3'],
    'Indiana': ['7', '6', '7', '8', '11', '11', '13', '12', '7', '7', '7', '7', '9', '2', '2']
}


maxmin = {}
for state, numbers in d.items():
    maxmin[state] = (
        max(enumerate(numbers), key=lambda x: int(x[1])),
        min(enumerate(numbers), key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
    )


print(maxmin)
```

Comment: `country != state` as a minor edit. Also, this won't work.

Comment: Thanks. I've also updated the code for get a `O(n)` complexity, and a more readable access to indexes. Won't work why ?

Comment: Forgot the `int` conversion. Now fixed.

Comment: `max` for strings compares the `ord` values

Comment: I have a question, let's say I replaced the first index in Illinois to empty string '', how would I get around that?

Comment: You could filter out the unwanted values before search for maximal/minimal, using something like `numbers = [n for n in numbers if n]`.